# Uploading shiny app at shinyapps.io - Application Failed to Start

Tags: r, shiny

I've looked at the other answers but whenever I deploy my shiny app at shinyapps.io, I get this error:

> An error has occurred The application failed to start. exit status 1

Otherwise the app works fine locally and the Deploy window says the app was successfully deployed.

There is no `setwd()` or `library(shiny)` in my code. In fact I did successfully deploy an earlier version of this same app once or twice before (though from a different computer), so I presume something else is going on.

```
#library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(bslib)


df <- structure(list(
  Group = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G1", "G1", "G2"), 
  Material = c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6"), 
  Capacity = c(1.26, 3.35, 3.47, 0.91, 2.86, 1.28), 
  Power = c(0.377, 1.006, 1.040, 0.272, 0.858, 0.384), 
  Energy = c(0.21, 0.39, 0.49, 0.15, 0.32, 0.21), 
  Capacitiveness = c(0.23, 0.27, 0.28, 0.25, 0.26, 0.28), 
  SR = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

cols <- names(df)
cols_non <- append('None', names(df))
SR_opts <- append('All', unique(df$SR))
size_opts <- cols_non[! cols_non%in% c("Group", "Material")]


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Results", windowTitle = "Plots"),
  p("Sample Text"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Performance Metrics",
             h3("Plots"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput("sr", "Select scan rate (mV/s)",SR_opts, selected = 'All'),
                 selectInput("x","x-axis",cols, selected = 'Energy'),
                 selectInput("y","y-axis",cols, selected = 'Power'),
                 selectInput("color","Color",cols_non, selected = 'Group'),
                 selectInput("size","Size",size_opts, selected = 'Capacity'),
                 radioButtons("rb", "Log Axis", 
                              choiceNames = list("None", "X", "Y", "Both"), 
                              choiceValues = list("None", "X", "Y", "Both"),
                              selected = 'None')
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 plotlyOutput("plot"),
                 plotOutput("plotgg"),

               )
             )
    ),
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filter_df <- reactive({

    if (input$sr == 'All') {
      df_fil <- df
    } else {
      df_fil <- filter(df, SR == input$sr)
    }
    df_fil
  })

  Xval <- reactive({
    filter_df()[,input$x]
    })
  
  Yval <- reactive({
    filter_df()[,input$y]
    })
  
  color <- reactive({
    filter_df()[,input$color]
  })
  
  size <- reactive({
    if(input$size =='None'){0.1
    }else{
      filter_df()[,input$size]
      }
    
  })

  logsc <- reactive({
    if (input$rb=='X'){list('log10','linear')}
    else if (input$rb=='Y'){list('linear','log10')}
    else if (input$rb=='Both'){list('log10','log10')}
    else{list('linear','linear')}
    
    
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot1 <- plot_ly(
      x = Xval(),
      y = Yval(), 
      type = 'scatter',
      mode = 'markers',
      color = color(),
      size = size()
    )
    
    plot1 <- layout(plot1, 
                    xaxis = list(type = logsc()[[1]], ticks ='inside'),
                    yaxis = list(type = logsc()[[2]], ticks = 'inside'))
    plot1
    
  })
  output$plotgg <- renderPlot({
    pl<-ggplot(filter_df(), aes(Xval(), Yval(), colour = color()))+
      geom_point(aes(size=size()))+
      theme_minimal()+
      labs(x =input$x, y = input$y)+
      guides(color=guide_legend(title=NULL), size = guide_legend(title = NULL))+
      theme(text = element_text(size = 15))+
      theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)))+
      theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)))#+
      #theme(text = element_text(family = "DejaVu Sans", color = '#555555'))

    if(!is.na(logsc()[[1]])){if (logsc()[[1]] == 'log10'){pl<-pl+coord_trans(x="log10")}}
    if(!is.na(logsc()[[2]])){if (logsc()[[2]] == 'log10'){pl<-pl+coord_trans(y="log10")}}
    

    pl
  }, res = 96)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit:**

According to the logs:

> 2022-10-25T09:03:45.550448+00:00 shinyapps[7255738]: Shiny application
> starting ... 2022-10-25T09:03:45.629722+00:00 shinyapps[7255738]:
> Error in value[3L] : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj
> object. 2022-10-25T09:03:45.629763+00:00 shinyapps[7255738]: Calls:
> local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
> 2022-10-25T09:03:45.629782+00:00 shinyapps[7255738]: Execution halted
> 2022-10-25T09:03:45.629786+00:00 shinyapps[7255738]: Shiny application
> exiting ...

I am not sure where this value[[3L]] comes from; because I changed all the 3L in the column SR and it's still there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look carefully through the logs in the dashboard of shinyapps.io. It should offer some clues why the app is failing to start.

Comment: Error in value[3L] : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object. I read elsewhere it points to some error in the code but I'm not sure of its origin here.

Comment: check the commas after close brackets in your `ui` object.